# Flutter convert different types of Image Class

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am new to Flutter. Apparently there are different classes for `Image`. The one I am working on are:

```dart
import 'package:image/image.dart'; // Image Class 1
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart'; // Image Class 2
```

I have loaded an asset image using `Image Class 2`. I do not know how to convert it to `Image Class 1` or vice versa. `Image Class 1` has two constructors `Image.fromBytes(...)` and `Image.from(Image other)` but the thing is the other class doesn't provide a byte array of image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image classes referenced are from the Flutter `image` class. The docs are [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html). The constructors that you listed aren't meant for converting between different image types. They are different builders for specific types of images. The `Image.from()` static method that you referenced is actually called a "named constructor". The `.from` constructor is a common Dart data class constructor used to effectively copy an object to another (not entirely dissimilar from `Object.assign({}, myObject)` in Javascript.

What you are trying to do is outside of the purpose of the named constructors you referenced in your question. Dart does provide a fairly robust image library in its standard library. [See Here](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/image-library.html).

If you are trying to render an image in flutter, you can use the following code as an example:

```dart
final Widget image = new Image(image: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/700'));
```

As an aside, there is [a very helpful VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator) to automatically generate data classes for your dart models.

**EDIT:** Showing how to load an asset image

If you are trying to load an asset image, use the following:

```
Image.asset(
        'assets/images/asset_image.png',
      );
```

Of course, you will need to register the asset in your pubspec.yaml. To do this, under the `flutter` section of your pubspec.yaml, add the following:

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Then, when you recompile, you should be able to load the assets. [Official docs on assets in flutter.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful for understanding the concept. I want to load an asset image, however the second Image library doesn't have an Asset Image loader. That's why I am considering to load them using standard image library.

Comment: If you are trying to load an asset image, use the following:
```
Image.asset(
        'assets/images/asset_image.png',
      );
```

Of course, you will need to register the asset in your pubspec.yaml. To do this, under the `flutter` section of your pubspec.yaml, add the following: 
```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```
Then, when you recompile, you should be able to load the assets.

Comment: I updated my original answer to show how to load an image from assets. See here for the official docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images